# How to install and use Dropbox in kde

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox doesn't quite work right under KDE because it relies on **nautilus**. There's a package called **kdropbox** available that's supposed to make Dropbox easier to use. I installed it, but calling **kdropbox** doesn't find anything.  The package is about ten years old and doesn't seem to be maintained. Does anyone here know anything about it?

Comment: This is the kind of answer  was hoping to get.  it doesn't require tampering with config files or anything nasty kike that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To use Dropbox with Dolphin file manager you have to install two packages - Dropbox and Dolphin plugins by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox dolphin-plugins
```

then run Dropbox for first time using its icon or `dropbox start -i` command. Provide your Dropbox credentials in the web-browser, wait it to run first sync.

Then open Dolphin, go to *Settings* → *Configure Dolphin* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), visit *Services* (or *Context Menu*) tab to enable *Dropbox* plugin, press *OK* to confirm the new settings. Restart Dolphin and enjoy:

[image: Dropbox on Plasma @ Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS]

Comment: I don't see Services under "Configure Dolphin, but There are a couple of Dropbox-related items in the Context menu