# Fix kfilebox unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, dependencies, dropbox

When I try to use Dropbox in Kubuntu, I soon discover that Dropbox normally requires nautilus, which does not play well with Dolphin.  The app **kfilebox**, available at Sourceforge, is supposed to deal with this  problem.  However, when I tried to install it I got a complaint about unsatisfied dependencies. How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Search on Repology for `kfilebox` [shows two versions of the application](https://repology.org/projects/?search=kfilebox) - Qt4- and Qt5-based.
The first will not work on your Kubuntu 20.04 LTS because of missed Qt4.
So we need to try the second - [Qt5-based version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/kfilebox-qt5-git) (with outdated [sources](https://github.com/marcpayne/kfilebox) from 2014 year) as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake extra-cmake-modules build-essential

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/marcpayne/kfilebox
cd kfilebox
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

and it will fail with message about missed KDE4 Config:

> ```
> ERROR: Could not find KDE4 kde4-config
> ```

So I would recommend to finish configuration of Dropbox plugin for Dolphin in [other thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1382621/66509). If you have problems - please comment there. On my test box it works normally.